# Python - compare values in a dataframe and if they are the same append the rows to a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I tried several things using pandas iloc and .append()
but my code doesn't work at all :(

what do i want:
i want to look in one row for the values of "dt" and "RT"
then i want to loop through the rest of the dataframe to check, if following conditions are met:
the value of "dt" should be in the range of +-0.1 to the compared "dt" value
and
also the "RT" should be in the range of +-0.1 to the compared "RT" value

if both criterias are met:
copy these 2 rows (all the rows) which fulfill these criterias to a new dataframe

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 760, 36.00, 14.1 , 15000], [2, 184, 36.05, 14.12, 11000], [3, 104, 36.95, 14.13, 12000], [4, 120, 34, 13, 16000]], columns=list(["ID","mz","dt","RT", "area"]))


a = [0,1,2,3]

for i in a:
    df2 = df2.append((df1.loc[(df1.loc[i, ["dt"]]) - 0.1) <= df1.loc[(df1.loc[i, ["dt"]]) <= (df1.loc[(df1.loc[i, ["dt"]]) + 0.1)) & (df1.loc[i, ["RT"]])])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you overcomplicated the matter with that chain full of conditionals. You can combine multiple conditions in a single ".loc" by simply adding "&" between them.

Here i show you how to apply it in your own example:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 760, 36.00, 14.1 , 15000], [2, 184, 36.05, 14.12, 11000], [3, 104, 36.95, 14.13, 12000], [4, 120, 34, 13, 16000]], columns=list(["ID","mz","dt","RT", "area"]))

df_list = []
                   
a = [0,1,2,3]

for i in a: 
    
    df_i = pd.DataFrame(data=None,columns=list(["ID","mz","dt","RT", "area"]))
    current_row_dt = df1.loc[i]['dt']
    current_row_RT = df1.loc[i]['RT']
    
    # Multiple conditions
    # ===================

    df_i = df1.loc[(df1['dt'] <= current_row_dt + 0.1) & (df1['dt'] <= current_row_dt + 0.1) & (df1['RT'] <= current_row_RT + 0.1) & (df1['RT'] <= current_row_RT + 0.1)]
    df_list.append(df_i)
```

You have to take into great account the parentheses, since python assigns "&" a higher precedence value than <=, ==, !=, etc.

- https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

If you have any questions feel free to ask.

PD: Note that, in my example, the rows obtained on each loop iteration are saved in a dataframes array rather than a single dataframe. I did this so you could see better what was added on each iteration, but you may wanna change that.

Answer (score 0):

thank you soo soo much for your help already :) It does what I want, but now I tried to improve it a little bit, in the way, that if NO entry in the dataframe can be found, which meets the criteria, then the initial row should be dropped.

So my idea is, that i want my data to be "compressed/cleaned".

So the final result should ONLY include data, where at least 2 rows or more match each other in terms of RT and DT.

If the a row is "unique" in terms of RT and DT, it should NOT be present in the final results.

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 760, 36.00, 14.1 , 15000, 22], [3, 104, 35.95, 14.13, 12000, 22], [4, 120, 34, 13, 16000, 22], [2, 184, 36.05, 14.12, 11000, 22],[8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 22],[7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 22],[6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 22]], columns=list(["ID","mz","DT","RT", "area", "random"]))

result = ([1, 760, 36.00, 14.1 , 15000], [2, 184, 36.05, 14.12, 11000], [3, 104, 36.95, 14.13, 12000])

the code below more or less does the job, but takes a huge amount of time, because of the two for loops ...

```
import pandas as pd

df1 =  pd.read_csv("test7.csv")
#df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 760, 36.00, 14.1 , 15000, 22], [3, 104, 35.95, 14.13, 12000, 22], [4, 120, 34, 13, 16000, 22], [2, 184, 36.05, 14.12, 11000, 22],[8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 22],[7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 22],[6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 22]], columns=list(["ID","mz","DT","RT", "area", "random"]))
df_list = pd.DataFrame()
final = pd.DataFrame()

a = len(df1)

df2 = df1

for i in range(a): 
    current_row_dt = df2.loc[i]['DT']
    current_row_RT = df2.loc[i]['RT']
   

    for b in range(a): 
        compared_row_dt = df2.loc[b]['DT']
        compared_row_RT = df2.loc[b]['RT']
    
         if compared_row_dt <= (current_row_dt + 0.1) and compared_row_dt >= (current_row_dt - 0.1): 
            if compared_row_RT <= (current_row_RT + 0.1) and compared_row_RT >= (current_row_RT - 0.1):
                df_i = df2.loc[b]
                df_list = df_list.append(df_i)

df_dup = df_list[df_list.duplicated(keep=False)]
df_final = df_dup.drop_duplicates()
print(df_final)
df_final.to_csv("test7_sorted.csv")
```